# What is the value 12800 in this code to output a char to a serial port?

Tags: c, kernel

This is a sample code to output a char to serial console:

```
#define COM1            0x3F8 // base port address

#define COM_LSR         5     // In:    Line Status Register

#define COM_LSR_TXRDY   0x20  //   Transmit buffer avail

static void
serial_putc(int c)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0;
         !(inb(COM1 + COM_LSR) & COM_LSR_TXRDY) && i < 12800;
         i++)
        delay();

    outb(COM1 + COM_TX, c);
}
```

The above code loops to check if serial port is available, and when it is, send a character `c`. However, why is the number `12800` chosen and not any other number?

Answer (score 2):

Its the clock rate which the serial port device supports in bits per second.

Comment: Thanks. Why do we need to loop over that number to check availability of the port? Could you show me an serial port specification that has that number as an example?

Comment: The following clock rates are supported on Cisco IOS Interface CEM Network Modules:

`200, 300, 400, 600, 800, 1200, 1800, 2400, 3200, 3600, 4800, 6400, 7200, 8000, 9600, 12000, 12800, 14400, 16000, 16800, 19200, 24000, 28800, 32000, 38400, 48000, 56000, 57600, 64000, 76800, 84000, 96000, 112000, 115200, 128000, 144000, 168000, 192000, 224000, 230400, 256000, 288000, 336000, 384000, 448000, 512000, 672000, 768000, 772000, 896000, 1024000, 1152000, 1344000, 1536000, 1544000, 1792000, 1920000, 2048000`

Comment: Why do we need to loop over that number to check availability of the port?  to ensure that data is completely sent. otherwise if you use serial_putc multiple times in your code, then data sent through serial may by out of synch or even miss some characters.

Comment: @theadnangondal so, I can replace `12800` with any random number, as long as it's equal or bigger than the preconfigured baud rate?

Comment: you have to set the baud rate before actually sending the data. And you have to receive at exactly the same baud rate. So if you change the baud rate to a higher rate and you are receiving at a different rate then surely there would be unexpected data (junk). If you change the rate at both sides then **YES**

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt this is a baud rate. Here it seems to be polling a status word to check when transmit buffer is available (hence the `COM_LSR_TXRDY`, transmit ready). When it is, it sends a char. The 12800 is just a limit to the time it waits. if it was not here, a problem could lead to an infinite loop. 12800 is probably arbitrary, low enough to end quickly if there is a problem, but high enough to wait for at least a transmit period (here it depends on the baud rate, but 12800 is NOT the baudrate). This code probably works perfectly fine with 10000 or 20000.

Answer (score 0):

baud rates. This ensures symbols to be transfered per second .

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9264/what-standard-uart-rates-are-there

Comment: I thought that baud rate = symbols/s, while bit rate = bits/s? That is, a symbol can be equal to one or more bits.